# Multiply values of vector in a certain interval?

Tags: r

How would I go about multiplying values of my vector in a certain range by a number?

What I have right now is this:

```
  img[img<a && img<b]<-img[img<a && img<b]*0.2
  img[img>=a && img<b]<- img[img>=a && img<b]*0.5 + ya
  img[img>a && img>=b]<-img[img>a && img>=b]+yb
```

Which is not working as expected.

What I want it to do: If the value is within the first interval, I'll multiply the original value it by a certain number. If it's on the second interval, multiply the original value by another number, thing like that.

I know how to substitute the original values for another number, but not how to manipulate the original number.

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `&`.  The `&&` operator returns only a single logical value.  `&` is vectorized and will return a logical vector the length of `img`

Comment: Thank you!!! That solved it!!!!